# Cutting last column in a file and creating new file in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have a txt file that has 5 columns. I want to delete the last column from the file and create a new file.  The new file should have first 4 column from old file.

Also the file is huge, 10M records. So is there any way the command can run in background? If not possible then its fine.

Input:

```
ID details2 details3 details4 details5
```

Output:

```
ID details2 details3 details4
```

Comment: Try: `cut -d' ' -f5 --complement file.txt > file2.txt &`

Comment: I wouldn't expect this task to take more than a few seconds, unless your storage is across the network.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the data columns in the input file do not contain any spaces you could do this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1-4 input.txt > output.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to keep the original file, this will edit it to remove the last word for every line:

```
ed file.txt <<'END'
1,$s/ [^ ]\+$//
wq
END
```

---

Update: don't use this method: timing below. Note this is the fish shell which allows escaped single quotes in a single quoted string

```
$ yes "ID details2 details3 details4 details5" | head -n 10000000 > file
$ wc file
 10000000  50000000 390000000 file
$ time sh -c 'printf "%s\\n" \'1,$s/ [^ ]\\+$//\' wq | ed file'
390000000
300000000
42.11user 34.21system 1:34.61elapsed 80%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1407060maxresident)k
1366408inputs+1894576outputs (4major+351780minor)pagefaults 0swaps

$ yes "ID details2 details3 details4 details5" | head -n 10000000 > file
$ time sh -c 'cut -d" " -f1-4 file > file.new'
0.98user 0.39system 0:01.58elapsed 86%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1700maxresident)k
480inputs+585944outputs (1major+154minor)pagefaults 0swaps
$ wc file file.new
 10000000  50000000 390000000 file
 10000000  40000000 300000000 file.new
 20000000  90000000 690000000 total
```

1min 34sec for `ed`, 1.5 sec for `cut`

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the last column, no matter how many columns your input file has:

```
awk 'NF--' inputfile >outputfile
```